# Unable able to update Freeform Pro from 2.2 to 2.5

Tags: craft3, plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform

I continue to get this error each time I try to update Freefrom.
I don't was to alter the table structure since data exists.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Instead of using the Craft updater, execute a composer require composer require solspace/craft3-freeform-pro